# python download video from website without knowing file name

Tags: python, video, download, youtube

i am wondering how it is possible to download a video from a website.

```
import urllib
testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("http://randomsite.com/file.gz", "file.gz")
```

I understand that the above script is able to download a file as long as you have the file extension.
What i am wondering is how do i download a file without knowing it's extension? 
How do i make a program that will download a video via inserting the videos url "Such as when you right click and copy video url"

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated !

Comment: You can try to issue a HEAD request first if anything from http headers response can be used for the download.

Comment: there should be a Content-Type together with its Content-Length from the header response. After getting this , you can then identify if it is a video or not.

Comment: So what you are saying is, header response>read content-type > append to url?

Comment: you mean you don't know the url of the file you want to download?

Comment: No friend sorry for the confusion, i know the videos url, just when i insert the url i dont have the file extension of the video ".flv .mp4" etc i was wondering how would i make the above script work for only having a videos url and not the file extension

Comment: You do not need to append anything on the url, actually for that file that you will need to download, there is a content-type given. You can identify this via `Content-Type` headers from the response & reading this key will let you know the kind of file you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['YOUR URL'])
```

I was able to download videos from a none youtube site with the above code :)