# Python - download video from indirect url

Tags: python, url, video, web-scraping

I have a link like this

```
https://r9---sn-4g57knle.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=10bc30daeba89d81&itag=22&source=picasa&begin=0&requiressl=yes&mm=30&mn=sn-4g57knle&ms=nxu&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjA0LmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=19&sc=yes&mime=video/mp4&lmt=1439597374686662&mt=1474140191&ip=84.56.35.53&ipbits=8&expire=1474169270&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,sc,mime,lmt&signature=6EF8ABF841EA789F5314FC52C3C3EA8698A587C9.9297433E91BB6CBCBAE29548978D35CDE30C19EC&key=ck2
```

which is a temporary generated redirect from (a link like) this link:
https://2.bp.blogspot.com/bO0q678cHRVZqTDclb33qGUXve_X1CRTgHMVz9NUgA=m22

(so the first link won't work in a couple of hours)

How can I download the video from the *googlevideo* site with Python?
I already tried youtube-dl because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33818090/5635812) answer, but it isn't working for me.

The direct URL would already help me a lot!

Comment: Did you try... downloading the `googlevideo.com` link within the couple hours limit? Repeat whatever you did to get (that first direct link) to video file and when a google video link is generated, download as soon as poss.   Look at python manual how to get file bytes from a link and use that `https://r9` style link as direct link to video file. It will range from from `https://r0` up to `https://r99` etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pycurl](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html)

```
#!/bin/usr/env python
import sys
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(c.URL, sys.argv[1])
with open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as f:
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, f.write)
    c.perform()
```

Usage:

```
$ chmod +x a.py 
$ ./a.py "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/bO0q678cHRVZqTDclb33qGUXve_X1CRTgHMVz9NUgA=m22" output.mp4
$ file output.mp4
output.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
```